# how to change the dojo gauge value in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

I've created the following gauge in index.html:

```
<div    
   data-dojo-type="dojox.dgauges.components.black.SemiCircularLinearGauge" id="g1"  
   interactionArea = "none" value="0" minimum="0" maximum="100"
   style="width:200px; height: 150px; margin-left: 40px;"></div>
```

Now I need to change the value after a user clicks on some button, in main.js file.
I understand that I need to use .set("value", X) function, but how do I get the gauge by Id? I tried document.getElementById('g1') and dojo.byId("g1") and it doesn't work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('g1')` and `dojo.byId('g1')` will return a DOM node, which by default does not have a built-in `set` method to invoke. Instead you should use `registry.byId` to retrieve the actual widget, which should have the `set` method you're trying to use.

```
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){
    var x = 5; //or something
    var gauge= registry.byId("g1");
    gauge.set("value", x);
});
```